# SQLite with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite

Hey folks,
I'm developing a small console app, that should parse text and place data to an SQLite db, app written in C# 3.5 + Entity Framework to persist data to the SQLite. Everything works fine expect that fact that after app did its job I can't find data in the SQLite file. During app running I can persist and read data from db but when it's done I open db in SQLite Administrator (http://sqliteadmin.orbmu2k.de/) and found no data. 
Does anybody know what's wrong? Thank you.

Comment: It could be an issue with your code...it would definitely help if you could post a sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So silly from my side, app after deploying to the bin folder copied db file there as well and manipulated with that db file, data is there.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you're not configuring your SqLiteConnection to use an in-memory database, or a temp file in the user store? SqLite can set up a database almost anywhere, for almost any length of time, and its default behavior may not be what you expect.

Comment: +1 - SQLite is often used as "in memory" for Unit Testing. Make sure you have it configured properly.

Comment: I'm creating "ADO.NET Entity Data Model" item in my class library project, contents for this model is chosen "Generate from database". Where is "Data source" is SQLite Database File I'm referencing on the disk. There is no any additional configuration settings. Could you please provide with more details?